# Find out if PowerPoint Smart Guides are active

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint

PowerPoint 2010 introduces so called Smart Guides as described [here](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-powerpoint/archive/2012/06/21/smart-guides-in-powerpoint-2010.aspx). You can choose to enable or disable this feature in the Grid and Guides settings dialog with the check box "Display smart guides when shapes are aligned".

I'd like to query the setting by code and have looked through the object model for a corresponding property but didn't find any. So have I overlooked it or is it not exposed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to query the registry

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\PowerPoint\Options\ShowSmartGuides

1 = on 0 =Off

Comment: Thanks for your input, John. I am also assuming that this may be the best approach. However, technically is doesn't necessarily give you the current setting but the state when PowerPoint started.

Answer (score 0):

We can Show and Hide custom Guides, I am using this in my application.

PowerPoint.Slide _pptSlide = null;
int SlideIndex = PowerPoint.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex;
_pptSlide = PowerPoint.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides[SlideIndex];
_pptSlide.Application.DisplayGuides = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;

Comment: That's useful, thanks, but it doesn't apply to the original question about SmartGuides, which is a different feature; they're the red guides that temporarily appear when one or another dimension of the shape that you're moving matches another shape.